# Gradle Project Sync failed but I see the same version in the gradle properties

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am doing a homework with Android Studio but I am not able to do anything since I have this error message:

> "Gradle Project Sync failed..."

I have checked in gradle-wrapping.properties to see if I use the same version which is the 6.9.1 and it says in my homework file:

*gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapping.properties*:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-bin.zip
```

It's my first time using Android Studio and I am very confused about this issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: the sync could also fail if there's an issue with the gradle build, is there any other message? can you run `graldew tasks` from command line?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Sometimes connection issues cause this. Try HTTP instead of HTTPS in distribution URL

Comment: @Aarjav I tried to use graldew tasks in the terminal but It says that it couldn't find the command,

Comment: @gtxtreme Yes I am connected to the internet on my computer. Also I saw that in the AndroidManifest all the ```android: ... ```are in red.

Comment: This is the message I have in Build ```Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.```
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 723ms

Answer (score 0):

So I found my solution, it's was very simple. All I had to do was to go in AVD Manager and create a Virtual Device.